# First button click + Second button click, utilize button's data

Tags: javascript, php

I made button for selecting timeslot.
And I would like to make when second-click, have a time slot on first click and second click and transfer this data.
for example ) first click on time slot `"12:00 -13:00"` and second click on time slot `"13:00-14:00"`
then firsttimeslot = `"12:00 -13:00"`, secondtimeslot=`"13:00-14:00"`
I try to use count on button, but it doesnot work!

```
<button class ="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="12:00 - 13:00 " count ="1"> 12:00 -13:00</button>
```

```
    $(".book").click(function(){
    var count = $(this).attr('count')
    if(count =="1")
        {
    var firsttimeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');
    $(".book").attr('count') = "2";
        }
        else{

      var secondtimeslot=$(this).attr('data-timeslot');

      $("#timeslot").val(firsttimeslot.trim());
      $("#secondtimeslot").val(secondtimeslot.trim());

        }
      }
    )

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using your counter variable outside of the function so it has a global scope. That way you can use it to track the state of which count you are on. See below:

```js
var count = 0;

$(".book").click(function(){
    count = count++;

    if(count == 1)
    {

        var firsttimeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');

        $(".book").attr('count') = "2";
    }
    else if( count > 2) {
        count = 0; // reset count after second click
    }
    else {

        var secondtimeslot=$(this).attr('data-timeslot');

        $("#timeslot").val(firsttimeslot.trim());
        $("#secondtimeslot").val(secondtimeslot.trim());
        }
      }
    )
```

You increment count whenever you run the function, and once you pass the second click you reset the counter to start tracking again.